# HDR problem while viewing the camera

Tags: 3d-view, camera, hdri

This happens only when I look from the Camera view while using a HDR.

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is exactly the problem?

Comment: @tacofisher look at the first picture...everything is in a sphere shape! The second picture is without the HDR!

Comment: Looks like you set the camera to Panoramic - Fisheye Equisolid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply these changes to your camera:
[image]